# Nono-cube - Ultimate Puzzle Giant

Tags: logical-deduction, visual, grid-deduction, three-dimensional, nonogram

### Prologue - Instructions

<sub>Shamelessly copied and pasted the following from @jafe's puzzle :P</sub>

This is a **three-dimensional nonogram**. The first square gives the enumerations for the Z-axis, top to bottom. The next sixteen squares depict the layers of a $16\times16\times16$ cube. Some rules:

- If a row or column has no numbers, that means that the composition of that row/column is **unknown**. Note that this is different than the usual practice in nonograms where a missing number means that the row/column has no shaded cells at all. In our case, such rows can be explicitly marked with a zero.
- The Z-axis enumerations are all single digits, so e.g. 11 means two stretches of one, not one stretch of eleven.
- The thin black lines in the middle are just visual aids. They're not meaningful to the puzzle itself.

### The Puzzle - Here we Go!

The Z-Plan and Labelling

> [image]

Layers 1 ~ 8

> [image]

Layers 9 ~ 16

> [image]

### Post-script - Thank You and Sorry!

> My deepest gratitude to @jafe in helping me a great deal in cluing this amazing puzzle. Thank you @jafe for your teaching!   
>   As a reward, @jafe will be **permanently banned** from solving this puzzle! (and also a +50 bounty from another puzzle of mine)

also...

> Thanks to you if you have upvoted the puzzle, and even more if you are trying to solve it!

I must apologise,

> for forgetting to note beforehand that the objective of this nonogram, and many of my others, is to interpret the nonogram and get a message. Sorry!

Comment: I feel like half the puzzle is just transcription :P

Comment: I would recommend a full test solve if that's something you are willing to do ;)

Comment: should there actually be any single ones?

Comment: I'll keep my eye out, of course.  As an aside, can I just confirm the order of the "z-plan"?  The top left cell reads "155".  I think that means 1 is closer to the top and the two 5's are closer to the bottom... right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this puzzle

> is a tribute to Alconja

building upon @Dark Thunder's answer

> we correct the orientation of the image to get this:
>  [image]
>  reading the letters in the correct way gives the phrase "Puzzle Master" and the symbol on the top left/bottom right looks like Alconja's current user icon

Comment: Oh.  I guess I don't know who that is, but I can presume they fit the title?

Comment: @DarkThunder you are correct

Comment: Well done! who should get the check?

Comment: up to you and @DarkThunder

Comment: i'm giving the check to you altho you answered later as you got the A_ reference. congrats!

Answer (score 5):

As viewed in the layer layout shown above:

> [image]

But the hidden message is better seen looking at the slices from left to right

> [image]
>
>
>  The message is doubled, and in my view also rotated and mirrored.  I would guess the letters are doubled up in order for the nonogrid to be more interesting.
>
>
>  I should note that there are (currently) two errors in the clues given, but given how the puzzle was turning out I knew to work around them.

Comment: Well done! who should get the check?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I solved the nonogrid and saw the message, but I didn't get the Alconja reference.  The two images above show the two perspectives I solved it in.  They share columns with eachother, and copying back and forth allowed for getting close to the solution.  Near the end I made some guesses on the last two letters to save time (the M and the A).

Comment: sorry but this time i'm giving the check to micsthepick altho they answered later than you as they got the A_ reference. sorry and keep it up! (upvoted)